# Printing on the graphics screen with lowercase/uppercase letters using CHAR command in Commodore BASIC 7.0

Tags: graphics, basic, commodore-128, text

The CHAR command in Commodore BASIC 7.0 on the Commodore 128 allows printing a text at a given position on the screen. Other than the PRINT command, CHAR also works in Hires graphics mode. Since the Commodore 128 has multiple character maps, how can I tell CHAR to print using the uppercase/lowercase charset? Changing the charset with CHAR$(14) in textmode does not seem to affect the behavior of CHAR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal method of changing between the uppercase/graphics character set and the lowercase character set on the Commdore 128 is by printing the control characters, like so:

`PRINT CHR$(142):REM SELECT UPPERCASE`, or,

`PRINT CHR$(14):REM SELECT LOWERCASE`

The same control characters will also work in your BASIC programs that use a bitmap screen mode and the `CHAR` command to print text on the screen. Just combine the appropriate `CHR$(x)` control code *with the string* that you are printing, like so:

```
10 GRAPHIC 1,1
20 CHAR 0,10,20,CHR$(14)+"HELLO, LOWERCASE WORLD!",0
```

This will print the text near the bottom of the 40-column screen in lowercase characters.